# Grid Batch Editing Telerik MVC Grid and Validation

Tags: telerik-mvc

My UI has a batch editable grid with column called Rank and fixed number of  records ( say 5 records and no paging ). The field Rank has to be validated and should always input in the ascending order ( say 1,4,6 7, 9). These inputs has to be validated before submitting and would like to show in-line validation message against the edited cell.

I tried following

Using  [Remote] validation attribute, but no way to pass the entire grid data.
Using OnSave client event, not sure how to add the in-line validation messages

Any suggestion on this would be greatly appreciated,

-George

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js** Javascript reference in your view page. And the remote validation will exactly post all the input parameters to the action method. There you can return either **true or false**.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass the entire grid data using [Remote] validation attribute, you have to make the grid data in this format for each data:

```
<input name="col1" value="col1_Value">
```

The name "col1" must be match as a parameter in your controller, so that the value can be passed.

You can achieve this by doing a little trick using jquery.